# Server side searching in React

Tags: reactjs, search

I am working on searching from API. I have 200,000 records and every 200 records take 7 seconds to load data, so if I do search on client side it is so time consuming.

What I want is to search inputed data directly from API and then to load searched data accordingly. How can I apply this in React?

```
<div className='search'>
                    <text className='srchtxt'>  Search  :-  </text>
                  <input className='inpt' type='text' onChange={event => this.setState({srch:event.target.id})}/>
                </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you need to check the API and see if they provide searching for you or not if yes you can send a request to their search endpoint and you will get limited data 
For example

```
Website.com/api/alldata
```

This will give you whole data

But if they provide search, it can be like this

```
Website.com/api/alldata/harrypotter
```

Then this brings all items related to Harry potter.
But as I said you need to check if they provide search or no

There is another way, you need to get API data to your personal server, and write searching in it your self, for example, you can use nodejs to filter data in server side and pass it to client

Hope you get the idea